# Rename the key in an Object

Tags: json

I have an Object like:

```
{A:{}, B:{}, C:{}, D:{}, E:{}}
```

and I would like to rename the keys from A B C D E to key1, key2, key3, key4, key5. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? What are you using or what have to tried to rename it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the current json object, remove the current key - value pair from object set the new key name and add it back to the object:

```js
var jsonData = {"A":{}, "B":{}, "C":{}, "D":{}, "E":{}};
var counter = 1;

console.log(jsonData);

$.each(jsonData, function(k, v) { 
        delete jsonData[k];
        k = "key"+counter;
        jsonData[k] = v;
        counter++;
});

console.log(jsonData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON you placed in a question is not valid. The correct structure should be like this:

```
{
  "A": {},
  "B": {},
  "C": {},
  "D": {},
  "E": {}
}
```

and actually this JSON is also valid:

```
{
    "key1": {},
    "key2": {},
    "key3": {},
    "key4": {},
    "key5": {}
}
```

so you can just rename the keys.

You may use online tool like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON object in case of problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function renameKey(obj, fromKey, toKey) {
    obj[toKey] = obj[fromKey];
    delete obj[fromKey];
}

var obj = {a: 5, b:6, c:7};
renameKey(obj, 'a', 'd');

console.dir(obj);  // Object b: 6 c: 7 d: 5
```

This assumes you're dealing with an object, but if you're starting with json, just call this on the json string to convert:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be easiest to use replace:

```
var jsonstring = '[{A:{}, B:{}, C:{}, D:{}, E:{}}]';

jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"A\":", "\"KEY1\":");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"B\":", "\"KEY2\":");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"C\":", "\"KEY3\":");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"D\":", "\"KEY4\":");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"E\":", "\"KEY5\":");
```